# При добавлении, редактировании записи/страницы появляется белый экран wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Гуглил по запросу белый экран смерти WP. Но там решения не подошли к моей проблеме.
Сайт был на одном хостинге, менялся тока доменное имя. С латыни на кириллицу (sport.oxe.su на формула-силы.рф).
Теперь когда захожу через wp-admin пишет

> Сервер не найден
>
> Firefox не может найти сервер
>   www.%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8b.%d1%80%d1%84.

Сама ссылка такая /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxn----7sbzjdbnqnqh8g.xn--p1ai%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Захожу в админку через wp-login.php и когда публикую или редактирую страницу/запись появляется белый экран, причем когда обратно захожу в консоль, страница/запись добавлена/редактирована.

Стоит еще последний woocommerce

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего из-за плагинов, попробуй их по отключай по очереди. И проверь

Comment: нет проблема не в плагинах, такое уже вытворял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте в базе данных, корректно ли указан домен.

Надо чтобы значения `siteurl` и `home` в таблице `prefix_options` (обычно `wp_options`) были записаны не кириллицей а в виде punycode. То есть конкретно у вас `option_value` обоих этих значений должны быть равны:

`http://xn----7sbzjdbnqnqh8g.xn--p1ai`

Если не получается добраться до URL через сам WordPress (`/wp-admin/options-general.php`), то проверить и изменить эти значения можно, например, с помощью phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Поменял и через админку и через pma, но когда захожу через wp-admin и в базе и на сайте обратно становится кириллицей, забыл упомянуть стоит еще woocommerce

Comment: То есть попасть в админку удаётся? Если да, то через специальный плагин надо исправить все ссылки. Например: Velvet Blues Update URLs. Если нет, то лучше использовать сторонний php-скрипт, типа того, что описан здесь: https://wpmag.ru/2015/move-wordpress/

Comment: спасибо, плагин решил проблему